# Explaining why $\Vert x_n\Vert _1=\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X_1$ respectively $X_2$ denote the space $C [a, b]$, $a <b$ with norm:

$$\Vert x\Vert_1=\int_a^b \vert x(t)\vert dt; $$$$\Vert x\Vert_2=\left(\int_a^b \vert x(t)^2\vert dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Using Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality for $x\in C[a,b]$ we have:

$$\Vert x\Vert _1 = \int_a^b\vert 1\cdot x(t)\vert\leq\left(\int_a^b dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_a^b\vert x(t)\vert^2 dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$\Rightarrow \Vert x\Vert _1 \leq M \Vert x \Vert _2, $ where $M=\sqrt{b-a}.$

On the other hand, the function $x_n$ defined below

$$x_n(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0, &\mbox{ if }
a \leq t\leq b-\frac{1}{n} \\n, & \mbox{ if } b-\frac{1}{2n}\leq t\leq b  \\\mathrm{affin}, & \mbox{ if } b-\frac{1}{n}\leq t\leq b- \frac{1}{2n}\end{array}\right.$$

With $t$ danote a $x$ axis and with $x$ danote $y$ axis.

Now we have: $$\Vert x_n\Vert_2^2\geq\frac{n}{2}\Rightarrow \Vert x_n\Vert _2\geq\sqrt\frac{n}{2}.$$ I understand this.

But I dont understand this: As you know that:

$$\Vert x_n\Vert _1=\frac{3}{4}$$

Thanks for your help and your attention.

Comment: did you try to calculate $\|x_n\|_1$ using the definition of the metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\|x\|_1=\int_{b-\frac{1}{2n}}^{b}ndt+\int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^{b-\frac{1}{2n}}\text{affin}=\frac{1}{2}+\text{area of triangle}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n})n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$.