# Explaining why $\int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^{b-\frac{1}{2n}}\text{affin}=\text {area of triangle}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Little earlier laid out an example of which can be found at:
[Explaining why $\Vert x_n\Vert _1=\frac{3}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903018/explaining-why-vert-x-n-vert-1-frac34)

I do not understand why: $$\int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^{b-\frac{1}{2n}}\text{affin}=\text {area of triangle}$$

I hope someone will help me understand. Previously, thank you

Comment: What is the the geometric interpretation of the integral of a positive function on $[a,b]$?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "affin".

Comment: @Hamou: Very good to meet you, is it possible to tell the details of the task you have previously solved, for which thank you very much

Comment: Sir @ Thomas Andrews: I've submitted a few example first, which you can find on but http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903018/explaining-why-vert-x-n-vert-1-frac34 but do not understand why it is so choice

Comment: I've  used this formula  just to simplify calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ affine positive in $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=k$. Then $f$ wrote 
$f(x)=\alpha x+\beta$, as $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=k$ we obtain $\alpha=\dfrac{k}{b-a}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{-ak}{b-a}$, hence $f(x)=\frac{k}{b-a}x-\frac{ak}{b-a}$.
$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\alpha(b^2-a^2)+\beta(b-a)=\frac{1}{2}k(b+a)-ka=\frac{1}{2}k(b-a)$.
Consider the three  points in the plan  $A(a,f(a))$, $B(b,0)$ and $C(b,f(b))$, the area of the triangle ABC: $\text{area}(ABC)=\dfrac{1}{2}AB\times BC=\frac{1}{2}k(b-a)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$.
You can see this on a drawing.